Woocommerce Split Orders for Partial COD Amount
I have this code which adds a COD payment option to my woocommerce store, so customer can pay partial payment as prepaid order and remaining outstanding amount as COD order.
The code is working fine,as it adds adds the COD option, and when selected it calculate the COD and Prepaid order amount.
The issue is that I want to create 2 separate orders, one prepaid with the portion of the amount and one COD with the remaining amount. Right now it only create one prepaid order, cod order is not placing up.

Here is the complete code(It's too long to paste here) :
https://pastebin.com/p4X1kRSs

